# disable video URL auto-embedding for a part of the post

Tags: embed, videos

In a post I want to add a list of URLs as a plain text. However, as some of URLs points to video sites, wordpress tries to embed those as videos. What is the way to disable this automatic embedding for a text fragment so in the rest of the post they continue to work?

If this require a plugin, is it possible at least to mark a particular URL to prevent its embedding?

Comment: When you want to remove all auto embeds: `remove_filter( 'the_content', array( $GLOBALS['wp_embed'], 'autoembed' ), 8 );`

Answer (score 3):

Well...

> > To embed a video or another object into a post or page, place its URL
> >     into the content area. Make sure the URL is on its own line and not
> >     hyperlinked (clickable when viewing the post).
>
> https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds#What_About_oEmbed_Discovery.3F

So, to "disable" embedding the simplest thing is to make sure the URL isn't on a line by itself, or provide a hyperlink.

You could (not an exhaustive list I'm sure):

- Wrap the url in a `span` block
- Add a dummy comment `<!-- -->` before or after the url
- Hyperlink it
- Create an ordered or unordered list -- `<ol>` or `<ul>`
- Add a `<br>`
- Create a shortcode, though this is by far the most (unnecessarily)
  complicated method.

Comment: I did not want to add any markup that could be affected by styling changes in future. But the comment trick is nice, thanks.

Comment: @IgorBukanov : there is virtually nothing that you can do that can't be effected in the future. Anyone who can edit the posts can break any "mark" you try to use to identify the "don't embed" urls, even if you use a shortcode.